Numerical example for a large system with a quadratic Hamiltonian and a state-dependent energy conservation matrix.
I am currently looking for physics motivated examples of the form $$\dot{x} = J(x)\nabla H(x),$$ where $J(x)^T = -J(x)$ is a skew-symmetric state-dependent matrix ($J: \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$), and $H(x) = x^TQx$ is a quadratic Hamiltonian with $Q^T = Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, i.e. more precisely $\dot{x} = J(x)Qx$. A classical example of this would be the rotating rigid body with the Hamiltonian $H(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{x_1^2}{I_1} + \frac{x_2^2}{I_2} + \frac{x_3^2}{I_3} \right) = \tfrac{1}{2}x^TQx$ where
\begin{align}
\label{eq:starrkSys}
\left[\begin{array}{ c }
\dot{x_1} \\
\dot{x_2} \\
\dot{x_3}
\end{array}\right] &= 
\left[\begin{array}{ ccc }
0 & -x_3 & x_2 \\
x_3 & 0 & -x_1 \\
-x_2 & x_1 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right] 
\left[\begin{array}{ c }
\frac{\delta H}{\delta x_1} \\
\frac{\delta H}{\delta x_2} \\
\frac{\delta H}{\delta x_3} 
\end{array}\right] \nonumber \\ &= \underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{ ccc }
0 & -x_3 & x_2 \\
x_3 & 0 & -x_1 \\
-x_2 & x_1 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right]}_{J(x) :=} \underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{ ccc }
\frac{1}{I_1} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{I_2}  & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{I_3} 
\end{array}\right]}_{Q=} \left[\begin{array}{ c }
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{array}\right].
\end{align}
applies. I am mainly interested in high-dimensional systems with a sparse matrix $J(x)$. I know that e.g. mass spring oscillators can be coupled together, as done in https://algopaul.github.io/PortHamiltonianBenchmarkSystems.jl/SingleMSDChain/, resulting in a very large linear ode system. Is something similar also possible for a physical system where $J$ is state-dependent and $H$ quadratic? Unfortunately, I come from the mathematical side and therefore have difficulty with such derivations.
